# Different click events for different objects on ListView row

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to implement different click event listeners for different sections of a single row of listview.

For example:

[image]

I have made 2 different linear layouts for the 2 different sections. Any particular way to implement the onclick listeners for the 2 different layouts?

Please suggest any other process of doing this if you have in your mind.

P.S. I cannot define click events in the custom adapter, as the Activity needs to fire the events from it with adding some data to it.

Comment: create a method in your activity and call it when you click on your layouts.

Comment: Mmmm good thought, let me try that out!

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: seems like it cannot access the resource!

Comment: check my answer @kittu88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `static` method in your `Activity` :

```
public static void YourMethod()
{

}
```

create `onClickListener` in `adapter` and call `activity` method.

```
holder.YourLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            YourActivity.YourMethod();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am getting this Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: you should update your question with the code you have done

Comment: It works, but if the method is static, then I am unable to access my non static variables. getApplicationContext() and startActivity() is also not working.

Comment: thn convert your context into activity and call that method

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! You made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement click Listeners in your adapter class like this-

```
layout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

layout2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: I know, forgot to mention, the activity which is showing the listview needs to handle the click events. It will push some data into it. with the event. So, is there a way to access the layouts from the activity and not the adapter?

Comment: you can do it by create an callback interface by the layout and get the callback in your activity